# Make MySQL Stored Procedure Low Priority/Not Lock Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, locking

I have a Stored Procedure in MySQL that locks tables while it is running. It is a fairly heavy procedure that can go on for up to a minute, and other requests that hit the DB during this time cause a deadlock error. Without rewriting the procedure, is there a way to make this Procedure low priority, or not lock the table at this time, so that other requests that come in take priority over it and are not blocked. I wouldn't want to cancel the procedure, but would like it to continue in the background.

I can see some settings like this in the creation of the procedure, but can't find what I need. Is this possible, and how can it be done? These are the settings:

```
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
```

Comment: Show the stored procedure. Lets see if it cane be written using transactions. Also `show create table {tablename}` details. Edit the question to include these details.

Comment: Those settings you show look like the contents of `mysqldump` output. None of them have anything to do with locking. If you want help with the stored procedure, you need to share the stored procedure code. I would guess you are doing UPDATE or DELETE statements without proper indexes to limit the scope of locks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, there is no way to make a procedure not lock tables while it is running with only trivial changes.

Additionally, assuming all of your tables are InnoDB (and in 2020, there are vanishingly few reasons for this to not be the case), there should be no table level locking going on unless your procedure is explicitly locking tables.

Comment: No table level locking (probably), however it could be taking row locks on _all_ the rows, if it is doing a locking query that examines every row. For example, an UPDATE that searches on a column without using an index.